# Best way to encode special chars in url

Tags: javascript, php, url, encode

What is the best way to encode special characters in a url? Let's say I pass an variable from javascript to a php script that way:

```
http://example.com/my sp3c!al var!a$le
```

What is the best way to encode that special characters (like whitespace, !, $, /, \ etc.)? Is there a method in javascript to encode it with a corresponding function in php to decode it there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of **`encodeURIComponent(yourvar);`**

Comment: This does not exactly work in my case. See my example url above. I use the part behind the domain to transfer it with htaccess rules to a query parameter. But if "my special variable" contains a slash, that slash gets indeed translated to %2F but causes problems, because the browser sees the slash a special char when calling that url. (like http://example.com/myspecial/variable) How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three ways

**encodeURI(yourvar)**
output `http://example.com/my%20sp3c!al%20var!a$le`

amd

**encodeURIComponent(yourvar)**

output `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmy%20sp3c!al%20var!a%24le`

**escape()**

output `http%3A//example.com/my%20sp3c%21al%20var%21a%24le`

using escape is not recomended because it is deprecated since ECMAScript v3.

functions is for **JavaScript** escaping, not HTTP.

Comment: But what if the "my special variable" part contains an slash? It gets encoded to %2F but causes problems, when calling the url, because the browser wants to open http://example.com/myspecial/variable and not transmit "myspecial/variable". How can I prevent this?

Comment: So the only way to fix that is to replace chars like "/" with other chars e.g. a ","so that the browser is calling the url correctly, right? This seems like a dirty fix..