# Set special char in URL

Tags: jquery

Can I set special char in my url with this jquery code:

```
$(".sl-video video source").attr("src", $(.videoImage #hfPathOfVideo").attr("value"));
```

This url looks like: Root/Videos/3/17-08-2016/
But I need in this form: ../Root/Videos/3/17-08-2016/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to encode special chars in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464812/best-way-to-encode-special-chars-in-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
$(".sl-video video source").attr("src", "../" + $(".videoImage #hfPathOfVideo").attr("value"));
```

Comment: Thnx #Karthikeyan.V